# How to isolate $x$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $$t = \sqrt {x^2 + a^2} - x$$

How do I isolate $x$ from this equation? I tried squaring the equation but it became pretty much complicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't square it right away; move $x$ to the LHS first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hyperbolic trigonometry, let $x=a\sinh u$.

Then $t=a\cosh u-a\sinh u=ae^{-u}$, so that $u=-\log\frac ta$.

$$x=-a\sinh\log\frac ta=-\frac a2\left(\frac ta-\frac at\right).$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** First, write $t+x=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$, Then, and then only, square both sides.

Answer (score 2):

$(t+x)^2=x^2+a^2$, so $t^2+2tx=a^2\implies x=\frac{a^2-t^2}{2t}$.

Answer (score 2):

we have $(t+x)^2=x^2+a^2$ thus we get
$t^2+x^2+2tx=x^2+a^2$ this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

$$ t+x=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\\ t^2+x^2+2tx=x^2+a^2 \\ 2tx=a^2-t^2 \\ x=\frac{(a-t)(a+t)}{2t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

$$
\begin{align}
t&=\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}-x\\\\
t + x&=\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\\\\
(t+x)^2&=a^2+x^2\\\\
t^2 +2tx+x^2&=a^2+x^2\\\\
t^2+2tx&=a^2\\\\
2tx&=a^2-t^2\\\\
x&=\frac{a^2-t^2}{2t}
\end{align}
$$